# How can I get a list of MySQL databases in PHP using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I wonder how can I get the list of MySQL databases in PHP using PDO without having to connect to a database first ( I mean no dbname in dsn )?

Usually I used to use the function mysql_list_dbs() but I no longer use mysql this way.

Comment: You can use `show databases` like @nick rulez mentioned; however you will still need to at least log in to the database server and create the connection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
show databases
```

or a query on the information_schema:

```
select schema_name from information_schema.schemata
```

Comment: Yeah I know the query for that but what will be my dsn ? I want to do that from inside PHP

Comment: @ta, you don't actually *need* specify a database to connect to when establishing a connection to MySQL.  Some other database engines aren't as forgiving.  After connecting, you can issue a `USE` command to switch to your database of choice.  Also @nick, +1 for `information_schema`

Answer (score 16):

Thanks nick rulez.
I made an example of DBs listing:

```
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'root';
$server = 'localhost';

$dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$server", $user, $pass );
$dbs = $dbh->query( 'SHOW DATABASES' );

while( ( $db = $dbs->fetchColumn( 0 ) ) !== false )
{
    echo $db.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
  $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", "root", "");
  $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
  $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Fail";
}

$rs = $dbo->query("SHOW DATABASES");
while ($h = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
   echo $r[0]."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Old answer, but shouldn't that be "echo $h[0]" ?

Answer (score 0):

Another method similar to Falcon's:

This script uses foreach instead of while and print instead of echo for the db names and the break tag is set up as it would be used with XML. It also uses the associative property, the column name, instead of the array index of the column in the returned row to display the desired result.

This assumes you have the PDO connection properly set up and = $dbconn.  Many times $db is used instead of $dbconn in examples.

```
$stmt ="SHOW DATABASES";
foreach($dbconn->query($stmt) as $row){
print $row['Database'];echo"<br />";
}
```